# My SharePoint server 2013, is not running any of the “Timer Jobs”

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, configuration, retraction, monitoring

I have SharePoint 2013 server with SP1. And I have noted that all the Timer jobs are not running, for example inside the Gradual Site Delete, it show last run as “N/A”, even I have try to run it manually:-

[image]

Also if I try to Retract a Farm solution, it keeps showing “Retracting ”, as follow:-

[image]

Can anyone advice on this please?

Thanks

Comment: How many servers you have in the farm?

Comment: make sure the Timer Services and SharePoint Admin services running on all server....check from services console

Comment: yes they are running and i only have one sarepoint server..

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE can you advice please ?

Comment: Did you see any thing in ULS logs and Event Log...that will help

Comment: the SharePoint logs are not showing any exceptions

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same.

Comment: have you restarted timer services in services.msc

Comment: also try with powershell to run the timer job.  take a reference from  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607833.aspx

Comment: Please see my answer for similar question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/234689/54698