# SharePoint 2013 Standard Timer Jobs not running for specific web application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs

Here's some background on our setup. We have 2 servers that host the web front ends that connect to our single SQL server.

In CA we have 2 web applications (besides the CA web app). One of these web applications does not have any errors. The other does not run its timer jobs (last ran date is NA).

We have restarted the timer service, cleared timer cache, and recreated the web application. None of these things have restored these timer jobs to proper operation.

Any ideas on what else we can try?

Thanks

Comment: have you seen any error in the ULS logs / event Log? try to start manually? what happen if you browse the site in the browser

Comment: We haven't uncovered any ULS log or Event errors. When we attempt to run manually nothing happens. The page simply closes without error. The site works fine outside of any functions that utilize timer jobs (so alerts do not work).

Comment: So not sure why but our timer jobs are working now. They kicked back on at 4:00am this morning. I wonder if the new month has anything to do with this?

Answer (score 2):

This solution helps me to solve a same problem.

1. Open SharePoint Management Shell and execute code below:

   ```powershell
   # Get WFE server on which you want to restore the timer service
   Get-SPServer -Identity "<name of WFE server>"
   $ts = $server.ServiceInstances | ? { $_.GetType().Name -like "*sptimerservice*" } | Select -First 1
   $ts.AllowContentDatabaseJobs = $true
   $ts.AllowServiceJobs = $true
   $ts.Update()
   ```
2. Open Central Administration and go to Manage content databases then select content database and select the server specified in the previous step as the Preferred Server for Timer Jobs.
3. Restart SharePoint Timer Service.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem and Making one of server from front-end Server to Application Server role resolved the issue.